# Price rules in Magento

Tags: magento

I have a problem with the price rules in magento version 1.5.1. I have a rule that defines the discount according to an attribute of the product , called fascia_sconto . I had a series of products that had an attribute that defined a discount of 20 % , but now I need to change the discount to be able to cancel it and put another on the same products .

I changed that attribute using store manager for magento , changing all the products concerned , putting the attribute in the rule that defines a discount to 0 , and then I applied this rule , thinking now that the discount was applied . But I have not noticed any change. Then I emptied the cache, reindexed everything, but nothing yet , there is always the old discount. But the mystery of all mysteries: if I go to a product of which I have modified the attribute, and save it , magically the rule, for that product, of course, is applied , then the item on the frontend has no discount . I have to resave 1,600 products , so I can’t certainly lose a whole day one by one to save all the products to make the rule active .

I also tried to make a rule for it , which should overwrite the previous one. I set a rule that defined a discount of 18 % on those products , putting between actions, “Stop processing more rules “ to “ yes”, so that the previous rule was no longer calculated , but that this was directly applied . But nothing , magento continues to calculate the discount starting with the rule of 20 (which no longer exists all over for those products , since I changed the attribute ) and then apply an additional discount of 18% on discount price! I’m not understanding anything, would you be able to kindly give me a hand ? Where was I wrong?

I hope I was clear enough, and I really hope you grow to be of help .

PS: I’m sorry for my bad English, but it’s not my primary language

Comment: I have resolved. I set the old rule to Priority 2, and the new rule to priority 0. This should mean it will use the new rule instead of the old rule. And now is working fine. So the problem was of configuring the rule with the correct priority. Thanks however @Malachy. My headeach is over, for now

Answer (score 0):

Applying price rules based on product attribute changes can be very difficult. I am sypmathetic to your cause.

It might not work but you are welcome to follow carefully my (paranoid) process for applying sale promotion rules:

- (change any product attributes relating to the sales rules)
- Re-index everything
- Refresh the caches
- 'Save and apply' the rule to apply it to the fresh indexes
- Re-index again
- Refresh the caches again

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but your steps has no effect :( the problem probably is the update of attributes using magento store manager. For a reason that i don't know, updating the attributes that i use for define the price rules has no effect using that program. The unique solution that i think is to use the default importer of magento, eventually if is possible, via terminal, and change the attributes with its. In locale it's working fine, but it take more execution time respect magento store manager :( However if you have an other idea i'm here to discuss and try it. Thanks

Comment: Is the Magento Compiler turned off? But I think you are saying that if you use the Magento Store Manager to update the attributes then your rules do not apply - as if the attributes are not stored correctly. Perhaps it is to do with stores and locales and websites so ensure your Magento Store Manager is applying the correct scope to the edited attributes - you could double check it by inspecting one product in the Magento admin area and looking at its attributes for different scopes. Then check the scopes of the price rules. Then I say repeat my steps above over and over until it works.

Comment: If I check the attribute on Magento backend, i see the value correct, so i think that magento store manager has done the modify correctly. Also, my magento store has only one store with one website and one language. So i don't have any other scope. the issue becomes more and more intricate... anyway thank you both for the availability and the help that you're giving me. Have you other ideas? I finished the ideas...

Comment: Well to be honest I don't really understand what you are trying to do. If you want to remove a discount, just delete or disable the promotion rule, don't try to set the discount to 0%. If you want a different rule just create a new rule. If you want to edit a discount from 20% to 18%, just edit the discount applied in teh existing rule. You don't need lots of rules cancelling each other out. I do know that getting rules to apply is complicated so take your time, triple check everything - it is easy to miss some sale logic and accidentally exclude all the products.

Comment: Just to be sure, you are flushing the Magento cache and the Cache storage too, yes?

Comment: I have to change the discount from 20 to 18. My rule for the 20's discount should not be changed because i have other product that use the rule. I created a new rule with a new attribute value for the products,with which I setup the new rule. Then I changed old attribute with new in some products, and I do everything that you suggest me. Now I will redo all the operation; maybe I forgot some step. I will tell you the result. Thanks for now.

Comment: Nothing... I modified all the attribute for the product interested for the rule, then I reindex all and flush cache, applied all rules and i redo the reindex and flushing cache, but nothing... I thought it was a simple task but I changed my mind unfortunately. This task make me crazy! Thanks again for the help anyway